# Pass token from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, token

I have build a login api in which when users login he will get a token  .And by using that token i am able to access other apis .

```
Authorization Token token=sadfghjkjhgfdsasdfghjgf
```

Like this I pass token by adding in header on each page.In my application controller I have added before_action :authenticate_user .So my question is I am building a form now and i need to pass the token which i have given above .This is not the form authenticity token so don't be confuse with that .I have search a lot but didn't got any relevant answer
Here is my solution which is not working

```
<%= form_for @home_workout, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
     <input type="hidden" id="user_token" name="home_workout[token]" value="sadfghjkjhgfdsasdfghjgf" />


          <%=f.text_field :title %>
          <%=f.text_field :description %>
          <%= f.file_field :home  %>
          <%= f.submit "Save"  %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Why don't you just store the token in a cookie or in the session?

Comment: so how will i pass from my form

Comment: I am not sure, but try next: `form_for @home_workout, { authenticity_token: 'your_token'}`. It's according: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Comment: this i have already tried and it doesn't work .By the ways i have already mention above i am not talking about authenticity_token